# how to synchronise a folder in a Web app with the website?

Tags: continuous-integration, kentico

I'm getting into Kentico development and I'm playing around with the continuous integration.

I have separated my VS solution from the website folder and publish my changes from the web application to the website.

however the CI system in Kentico saves it's serialized items in the /CMS/App_Data/CIRepository folder in the website.

So I need a way to easily get the changes in that folder back into my VS solution, so I can check them in to my source control.

In other words a folder that is synched between the website and VS web application. what would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with.
a new/second developer can install an empty site.
Then create a symbolic link folder in his site pointing to the CIRepository folder that is inside the solution folder (which is under source control).

mklink /d D:\Sites\KenticoReferenceQA\CMS\App_Data\CIRepository D:\Projects\KenticoReferenceQA\CMS\App_Data\CIRepository

This will create the CIRepostory folder in you website folder, now any changes made in this folder is mirrored in the project folder and detected by Visual Studio and your source control of choice.

I have also added a post build script that triggers the powershell script to run continuous integration in the website. this will then update the website when you build.

Answer (score 1):

You should NOT have CI running on your live, qa or staging sites. CI is for multiple developers working in their own local environment not a shared instance which can be accessed by others.

So for your case I'd suggest turning off CI on the server. You may also, if it's a physical server install your repo tools and commit and restore your files but it's not how it was meant to work.

Comment: Hi Brenden. Sorry if I wasn't clear. all this is indeed on a developer machine. With the purpose of working out how to collaborate in a multi developer team.

Comment: So the idea is each developr would have a website folder where Kentico is runnnig and a project folder where the VS solution exists. A source control system would be used to sync the CI (and other) files between developers. And now I'm working out the sync between one developers CI folder in the project folder and the CIRepository folder inside the website folder.

Comment: Your solution folder will hold your solution file as well as your Kentico project and any other projects you want (standard setup).  Your Kentico project will always hold the CI files under the /App_Data directory.  I don't believe there is a different way to setup storage of them in a different location.  So your repository should be set at the solution folder level (root of the solution) to capture all those changes.  If you want specifically to exclude Kentico system files (not recommended), then add a gitignore for those.